# Textbox not support for property and menthod in VBA ppt

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

Here is my code

```
Sub Loadde()
If Slide3.Shapes("MA_VONG") = 1 Then
    Slide5.Shapes("Q1").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("1").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q2").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("2").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q3").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("3").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q4").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("4").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q5").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("5").TextFrame.TextRange
ElseIf Slide3.Shapes("MA_VONG") = 2 Then
    Slide5.Shapes("Q1").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide7.Shapes("1").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q2").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide7.Shapes("2").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q3").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide7.Shapes("3").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q4").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide7.Shapes("4").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q5").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide7.Shapes("5").TextFrame.TextRange
End If
End Sub
```

At first, it work fine but after that, it showed an error that the Qs (in Slide 5) were not supported
I tried to make it more simple and it still does not work.

```
Sub Loadde()
If Slide3.Shapes("MA_VONG") = 1 Then
    Slide5.Shapes("Q1").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("1").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q2").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("2").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q3").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("3").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q4").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("4").TextFrame.TextRange
    Slide5.Shapes("Q5").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("5").TextFrame.TextRange
End If
End Sub
```

Can somebody explain to me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Please post the exact wording of the error message and indicate the line of code that is highlighted when the message appears.

Comment: The error message is: "Run time error '438':Object doesn't support this property or method" and none of the lines is highlighted when the message appears.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

First, it's not clear whether you've DIMmed your variables elsewhere.

Next, **Slide3.Shapes("some name") = 1** will fail. There's no such property.  What exactly are you trying to test for here? The text in the shape or that the shape exists at all?  Or something else?

Finally, just to be sure, IS there actually a shape named 1 on Slide6 or are you trying to reference the first shape on the slide, in which case you'd use Slide6.Shapes(1)  (not "1" in quotes).

```
Sub Loadde()
If Slide3.Shapes("MA_VONG") = 1 Then
    Slide5.Shapes("Q1").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide6.Shapes("1").TextFrame.TextRange
    ' ...
ElseIf Slide3.Shapes("MA_VONG") = 2 Then
    Slide5.Shapes("Q1").TextFrame.TextRange = Slide7.Shapes("1").TextFrame.TextRange
    ' ...
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I dimmed my variables on the slide (shape), the text "1" is the name of the shape, and it still not working :<

Comment: Fine. But as I mentioned, "If Slide3.Shapes("MA_VONG") = 1 Then" and "Slide3.Shapes("MA_VONG") = 2 Then" simply won't work. Won't even compile in fact. You'll need to fix that problem also. If it still doesn't work after that, post the current version of your code.